# Unity 3D Using C# Using A keyboard press to call a scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am programming a game's UI currently, and I am trying to figure out how to call a scene with a key press. In this case the Escape key. I know how to summon a scene in general but incorporating a button press from keyboard is where I am stuck at.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void pausemenu()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("menuPause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Er...have you researched at all on how button presses can be detected in Unity?

Comment: Check for escape keypress in the Update function then load scene? `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)){...load scene};` Which part is complicated?

Comment: @Serlite i did but everything i found on the unity forums did not work for me. And trying to google the answer things became inconclusive as they were too outdated.

Comment: @Programmer The part of not knowing or finding the getkey function last fourm i checked didnt mention it. =D thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Escape))
    {
     Application.LoadLevel("YourSceneNameHere");
    }
}
```

But you need to add your scene to **BuildSettings**.

Go: File>Build Settings  (Or Ctrl + Shift + B)
If your scene which you want to add to list is already open simply press "Add Open Scenes"

You need to have 2 scenes at least to load one from another, or you can load the same scene again within, which can be useful for some situations.

After adding the scenes you want, when you press "Escape" in this situation;

*Your scene(where your "loadSceneScript") needs to open and your script needs to be attached to a gameobject*

Your scene will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
     {
          //load the scene
     }
}
```

The thing is this script must be available in the scene all the time. To make it persistent you also have to add this to the script:

```
void Awake()
{
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```